# $.ajax succes:function does nothing at all, while receiving answer

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

This is bugging me for over 2 hours now, and I just don't see it.

I have a form, which has it's validation in PHP. So what I do is create an AJAX-call, on based on the returned response I submit, or don't submit the form. This is my AJAX-call:

```
    $("#savePO").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'ajax/newpo_check_ajax.php',
            data : $("#newpoform").serialize(),
            succes : function(respons) {
                alert(respons);
            }

        });
});
```

The response page (newpo_check_ajax.php) is just:

```
<?php
echo "AJAX IS WORKING!";
?>
```

When I check Firebug, it states that the response is indeed what it should be ("AJAX IS WORKING!"), but whatever I try, I don't get the response to alert!

The above jQuery code is on the bottom of my page, since it didn't work at the top (inside `$(document).ready())`.

Any help is appreciated! :)

EDIT: Unfortunately I wasn't able to read properly anymore. I forgot an S in success, on which.

Comment: Make sure your server responds with HTTP Status 200 - OK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct spelling is `success`, not `succes`. You're missing an `s` at the end.

Comment: Also with 'respons' (response)

Comment: @Utkanos: That won't make a difference, though.

Comment: @Utkanos: That is just a variable name. You can give anything there

Comment: Yeah I know, I wasn't saying it would - just pointing out that there's two spelling issues, not one

Comment: Sometimes you just want to high five yourself in the face.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "succes" with one s it should be "success"